# Why can't I call a method with an array variable?

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to print out a simple code but I do not seem to be able to pass the array variable of the method. Sorry if it is something obvious, I am only starting with Java.
I am getting the "The method asd in the type MyClass is not applicable for the arguments (int,int,int,int)

```
public int asd(int[] nums) {
      int count = 0;
      // Note: iterate to length-1, so can use i+1 in the loop
      for (int i=0; i < (nums.length-1); i++) {
        if (nums[i] == 6) {
          if (nums[i+1] == 6 || nums[i+1] == 7) {
            count++;
          }
        }
      }
      return count;
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    System.out.println(asd(1,22,3,4,2,2,2));

}
```

Answer (score 3):

The method is expecting a single parameter. You are attempting to pass each integer as a separate parameter.

Enclose the values in `{}` and prefix it with `new int[]` to create an Array literal:

```
 System.out.println(asd(new int[] {1,22,3,4,2,2,2}));
```